# Количество вершин в дереве на N-уровне. Любой язык - важен сам алгоритм

Tags: дерево

Надо алгоритм для поиска в N-уровне кол-во вершин в дереве. 
Для заметок дерево не Бинарное.

Comment: Структуру узла Вашего дерева приведите.

Answer (score 4):

Это все тоже дерево, которое бинарное, но вы так не считаете? Тогда вот. Корень - 0 уровень.

```
int countOnLevel(BinaryTree * root, int N)
{
    if (root == 0)
        return 0;
    if (N == 0)
        return 1;
    return countOnLevel(root->left, N - 1) + countOnLevel(root->right, N - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проходим все дерево до глубины `n`, считаем сколько было найдено вершин.

Если язык любой... Например, нспользуя Haskell с [`Data.Tree`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/containers-0.4.0.0/Data-Tree.html) можно выразить это так:

```
levelSize :: Tree a -> Int -> Int
levelSize t n =
    length $ (iterate (concatMap subForest) [t]) !! n
```

(В Haskell используются ленивые вычисления, поэтому в бесконечный список, созданный `iterate`, оно глубже нужного не полезет.)

Проверяем:

```
Prelude Data.Tree> putStrLn $ drawTree t
root
|
+- l1n1
|
+- l1n2
|  |
|  +- l2n1
|  |
|  `- l2n2
|
`- l1n3
   |
   `- l2n3

Prelude Data.Tree> levels t
[["root"],["l1n1","l1n2","l1n3"],["l2n1","l2n2","l2n3"]]
Prelude Data.Tree> takeWhile (> 0) $ map (levelSize t) [0..]
[1,3,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Haskell есть, еще вариант на Prolog'е.

```
% Дерево определяется значением узла и списком детей,
% которые тоже являются деревьями
list=tree*
tree=tree(symbol,list(tree)).

% Длина списка
length([],0).
length([_|T], L):-length(T, TL),L = TL + 1.

% Корневой уровень не считается, там 1 всегда
% 0й уровень - дети корня...
% Спускаемся вниз по дереву на глубину N
tree_n(0,tree(_,X),Z):-length(X,Z).
tree_n(N,tree(_,[X|Y]),Z):-N1=N-1,tree_n(N1,X,Z1),tree_nl(N1,Y,Z2),Z=Z1+Z2.

% Обходим хвост списка поддеревьев
tree_nl(N,[],0).
tree_nl(N,[X|Y],Z):-tree_n(N,X,Z1),tree_nl(N,Y,Z2),Z=Z1+Z2.

% Считаем количество узлов на 0 уровне, получаем 3 поддерерва у корневого узла
tree_n(0, tree("root",[ tree("l1n1",[ tree("l2n1", []), tree("l2n2", []) ]), tree("l1n2", []), tree("l1n3", [tree("l2n3", []) ]) ]), X),write(X),nl,fail.
```

ЗЫ Не так красиво, конечно, но зато причудливо!

Comment: Спасибо конечно... Но как я функциональным способом опишу на С это алгоритм. А так проверил работает, конечно. Мне бы императивным способом.